# Use javascript variable in html option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, scriptlet

I found few posts related to my question but none of them seems to be apt for my case. I have a JSP page in which at a particular point I need to retrieve the options selected in a **chosen** select dropdown for which the javascript code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = [];
        var listItems = $("#brand-id li span");
        listItems.each(function(idx, span) {
        var brand = $(span).html();
        arr.push(brand.toString());
        });
</script>
```

Now I need to send the values saved in **arr** to the server. For this the **option** tag is used. Code is as below:

```
<option selected="selected" value="<%=arr[i]%>"><%=arr[i]%></option>
```

My Compiled HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Brand:</label>
    <div id="brand-id" class="col-sm-9">
        <select id="brand-select-id" data-placeholder="Select Brand" name="brand" multiple="" class="chosen-select" style="display: none;">
                        <option selected="selected" value="A">A</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="B">B</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="C">C</option>
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                        <option value="E">E</option>
        </select>
        <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 83%;" title="" id="brand_select_id_chosen">
            <ul class="chosen-choices">
                <li class="search-choice"><span>C</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="2"></a></li>
                <li class="search-choice"><span>A</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a></li>
                <li class="search-choice"><span>B</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a></li>
                <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Select Brand" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="chosen-drop">
                <ul class="chosen-results">
                    <li class="result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">A</li>
                    <li class="result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="1">B</li>
                    <li class="result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="2">C</li>
                    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">D</li>
                    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">E</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My confusion is how do I use arr[i] in the **option** tag and is it even possible. If not, how can I do the same task in some other way. Thanks.

JSP file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Brand:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select data-placeholder="Select Brand" name="brand" multiple class="chosen-select col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
            <%
            // user.get("brand") gets the already selected brands by the user
            // masterRecords.get("brandslist") gets the complete list of brands from LDAP whether selected or not selected
            String brands="";
            if(user.get("brand")!=null && !user.get("brand").isEmpty())
                brands =user.get("brand").toLowerCase(); 
            if(masterRecords.get("brandslist")!=null && masterRecords.get("brandslist").length > 0){
            for(String brand:masterRecords.get("brandslist")){
                if(brands.contains(brand.toLowerCase().trim())){%>
            <option selected="selected" value="<%=brand.trim().toLowerCase()%>"><%=brand.trim()%></option>
                <%}else{%>
            <option value="<%=brand.trim().toLowerCase()%>"><%=brand.trim()%></option>
                <%} 
            } 
            }%>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the same JSP file I have added the JS code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var select = "";
    var arr = [];
    var listItems = $("#brand-id li span");
    listItems.each(function(idx, span) {
      var brand = $(span).html();

      arr.push(brand.toString());

    });
    //arr having values
    console.log(arr);


    select = ' <select id="brand-select-id" data-placeholder="Select Brand" name="brand" multiple="" class="chosen-select" style="">';
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      //appending options in selectbox
      select += '<option  selected="selected"value="' + arr[j] + '">' + arr[j] + '</option>';

    }
    select += '</select>';
    //append select to div 
    $(select).appendTo('.select');
</script>
```

JSP file updated with your code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Brand:</label>
    <div id="brand-id"  class="col-sm-9">
            <%
            // user.get("brand") gets the already selected brands by the user
            // masterRecords.get("brandslist") gets the complete list of brands from LDAP whether selected or not selected
            String brands="";
            if(user.get("brand")!=null && !user.get("brand").isEmpty())
                brands =user.get("brand").toLowerCase(); 
            if(masterRecords.get("brandslist")!=null && masterRecords.get("brandslist").length > 0){
            for(String brand:masterRecords.get("brandslist")){
                if(brands.contains(brand.toLowerCase().trim())){%>
            <div class="select"></div>
                <%}
                //else part left for now
            } 
            }%>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 1: The complete code from JSP file has been added. I was playing with the code generated by the 'chosen' plugin to get the custom sorting done.

Comment: can you show your html as well for `span` ?

Comment: @Swati HTML code has been added

Comment: Your `arr` will have values `C,A,B` you need to put this in `options` ,am i right ?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: Currently, when I press submit, values A, B, C are being submitted irrespective of the order that I have selected. So, wanted to achieve it through JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can append value of array to your `options` using `for-loop` and then use `appendTo` method of jquery to put that options inside  `<div id="select"></div>`.Working example :

```js
var select = "";
var arr = [];
var listItems = $("#brand-id li span");
listItems.each(function(idx, span) {
  var brand = $(span).html();

  arr.push(brand.toString());

});
//arr having values
console.log(arr);


select = ' <select id="brand-select-id" data-placeholder="Select Brand" name="brand" multiple="" class="chosen-select" style="">';
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  //appending options in selectbox
  select += '<option  selected="selected"value="' + arr[j] + '">' + arr[j] + '</option>';

}
select += '</select>';
//append select to div 
$(select).appendTo('#select');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Brand:</label>
  <div id="brand-id" class="col-sm-9">
    <!--inside this div option will display-->
    <div id="select"></div>
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 83%;" title="" id="brand_select_id_chosen">
      <ul class="chosen-choices">
        <li class="search-choice"><span>C</span>
          <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="2"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-choice"><span>A</span>
          <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-choice"><span>B</span>
          <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Select Brand" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;"></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Update 1**:

As i have already said in comment that you need to make some function so that it be called whenever options are `selected` or `deselected` from the `chosen` select-box.In below code i have used `change` event to check if any change occur in select box then call function to do required update.Working code:

```js
$('select.chosen-select').chosen();
//call function when page load
update_values();

//whenever changes occur on select-box i.e: if item is removed or added this will be called
$(document).on('change', 'select.chosen-select', function(obj, result) {
  //calling function
  update_values();
});


function update_values() {
  var select = "";
  var arr = [];
  var listItems = "";
  //this will refresh values in chosen-select 
  $('select.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  listItems = $("#brand-id li span");

  listItems.each(function(idx, span) {

    var brand = $(span).html();
    //adding values in array
    arr.push(brand.toString());

  });

 select = ' <select id="brand-select-id" data-placeholder="Select Brand" name="brand" multiple=""  style="">';
  for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    //appending options in selectbox
    select += '<option  selected="selected"value="' + arr[j] + '">' + arr[j] + '</option>';

  }
  select += '</select>';
  //add select to div
  $('.select').html(select);




}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1">Brand:</label>
  <div id="brand-id" class="col-sm-9">
    <select id="brand-select-id" data-placeholder="Select Brand" name="brand" multiple="" class="chosen-select" style="width:300px">
      <option selected="selected" value="A">A</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="B">B</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
    </select>

  </div>
<!--select box will come inside this-->
  <div class="select">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The compiled code comes somewhat like this--https://jsfiddle.net/kohjbxt3/

Comment: I am using jquery version "1.11.1" and changing it is causing problems for rest of the code.

Comment: You cannot have div with same `ids` ,you need to use `class` for that ,also above code will work on `1.11.1` version as well . Update your fiddle with `jquery` as well and let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried the same with class instead of IDs but it still does not work. Also, I noticed that when I run the JS code to get the array in console, I get the desired output but when the same is done via code on submit button, an empty array is returned. Could it be due to the code of 'chosen' plugin not being rendered at that time as I was trying to use the compiled code of  this plugin to get the array.

Comment: Can you make `fiddle` with problem your currently facing ,it would be easy to understand?

Comment: fiddle won't work as it is a JSP with scriplets. I want to show you the exact code. Is there some other place where I can paste the code?

Comment: where is `submit` button in above code ? also how do you select options,as current `js` code take values from `chosen-choices` this so,when page is load are these values  present or not ,or it is selected afterward if yes .. then you need to tackle this by putting js code under `function`..then , whenever user select some option it will call the function and add selected values in select-box .

Comment: The submit button just updates the values changed in the present page and stays on the same page after doing so. Code: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left" name="submit" id="submit1" value="Update" />` Yes, when the page loads the already saved brands that come from __user.get("brand")__ are preloaded in the options pane as selected brands and in the dropdown the already selected brands are unselectable and rest of the brands come as selectable. When one brand from the selected list is crossed from the pane, it also comes as selectable in the dropdown list.

Comment: Yes,because that `js` is working only 1 time when page gets load ..so even if afterward any option is removed that will have no affect, you need to add a `function` which will be called whenever a option is crossed ,so that it will again load the `select-box` and only required option is present.

Comment: How would we apply function on this? Could you please illustrate (I am very new to JS) as when we cross an option or select an option from the dropdown only the `li` tags under `chosen-choices` and `chosen-results` get updated and the `<option selected="selected" ....>` remains as it is until form is submitted.

Comment: Now , check updated code let me know if it works or not .

Comment: My main aim of saving the brands in an array was to maintain the order in which they were selected but here when I run the code the order is not maintained. Even if I select B, C, A, the order that is displayed is A, B, C and not B, C, A

Comment: where are you showing values ? i have added another dropdown i.e : here `<div id="select"></div>`  will your value will get display , whatever you made changes in your `chosen-select box` that will get add to that dropdown. You need to submit values for dropdown which is generated by `js` code then only values will be in required order.Also,above code is just a demo , you need to implement that in your code as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time. Will make changes in my code and let you know.